# What is the meaning of the comma in this case?

Tags: commas, relative-clauses

> 1. He rides a bike reading the book. (with no comma between bike and reading)
> 2. He rides a bike, reading the book. (with a comma between bike and reading)

In the sentence above, What is the difference in the sentence 1 (no comma) and 2 (with comma)?

Comment: If the linked question does not fully address your query, you can comment on the answers there, or edit this question to explain **exactly** what is unclear. Merely restating the question is not useful to anyone.

Comment: Sentence 1 means: There is a bike that is reading a book. (Which is something that Lewis Carol might have written or Dr. Seuss) A man rides on this "reading bicycle". Instead did you want to say: "A man reading a book, rides a bicycle"? The comma separates the two simultaneous actions. It *means* nothing.